# Overwriting saved eip to point to stdin?

Tags: buffer-overflow

A student in my class came up with a technique for exploiting buffer overflows that I have never seen before. (Frankly, I am surprised that it works.) I am curious if (1) anyone has seen a reference to anything like this before, and (2) whether this type of attack is too "fragile" to work in general.

Basically, the idea of the exploit is to provide input of the form

```
AA...A BBBB CC...C,
```

on stdin, where `AA...A` causes the overflow; the saved eip is overwritten with `BBBB`; and `CC...C` is the shellcode. Rather than overwrite the saved eip with the address of `CC...C` on the stack, however, he overwrote the saved eip with the address in memory of stdin (well, actually, `stdin+length(AA...A BBBB)`).

(For those who are curious: the reason he did this was because the address of `CC...C` on the stack contained a null byte and hence it was difficult to overwrite the saved eip with that value.)

If this works in general, it seems like this would be another way to circumvent ASLR.

Thoughts?

Comment: "the address of memory in stdin" - what does that mean?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: My guess is that it points to the point `CC...C` is stored to.

Comment: @MikeKwan: But the OP says that he doesn't point at the destination of the copy...

Comment: I understood it to mean pointing into the `stdio` buffer on the heap.

Comment: @geekosaur: Does one know the address and state of that *a priori*?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, there's no portable magic, but if you're willing to stick to `glibc` and there's no address randomization, you can make a pretty good guess.

Comment: @geekosaur: That was my assumption.  So I'm pretty sure the answer to the OP's question is "no, this doesn't work with ASLR".

Comment: Yes, I mean the stdio buffer on the heap. What is interesting here is that the exploit works <em>even if the shellcode does not get written onto the stack at all</em> (e.g., if the overflow allows the saved eip to be overwritten, but does not copy the shellcode itself).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: so does ASLR randomize the location of stdio on the heap?

Comment: @user432944: As I understand it, the location of the heap itself is randomized.